# Update Eclipse project type through a script

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, scripting

I have inherited an old java project, where different team members are using different development tools; some use emacs, some netbeans, I use eclipse. Hence when this project is checked into the version control, it's just a bunch of java files and ant build files.

Every time there is a new branch or so, I checkout the project in my eclipse through subclipse plugin and generate some dependent jars, put them in classpath, then set up the source folder etc etc. This is becoming very tedious as I help out others with same configuration if they're using eclipse. Is there a way I could have some script which I can run on the project to convert and restructure it to an eclipse project?

Comment: And why not just commit eclipse-, netbeans-, and emacs-specific configuration files? They won't collide with each other and your team will lead a happier, more productive life.

Comment: Unfortunately people here are too sensitive about what goes into the repository. I can say around 20% of us use eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the Ant build create the .project and .classpath files for you.  I've done this myself with the [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) suite, since those files are just XML documents.  Add them to the svn:ignore property so your twitchy teammates don't get upset.

[There appears to be an old ant task that does this for you](http://ant-eclipse.sourceforge.net/), but I haven't used it myself.